# Delimit an urban area on a surface with QGIS

Tags: raster

I want to delimit an urban area using a raster analysis in QGIS. Is there a Plugin that performs this procedure?

Comment: Your description is very vague, can you expand a little more on what data you have, how you define 'urban area' and what sort of accuracy you're hoping to achieve. Please also describe the attempts you've tried so far so that we're not suggesting approches you've already investigated and found unsuitable.